# Is there a way to "mock" a vcenter server?

Tags: mocking, vmware, fog, vcenter

This question might sound a bit odd but here it goes:
I'm writing a bunch of applications that connects to VMware vcenter api , now as i mainly code on my laptop i was wondering if there's some way to "mock" a vcenter server so i can connect to it from my code .
This would avoid me having to connect to the VPN every time i need to test anything.

I've been checking **FOG.io** and even do they do have a vcenter mock , it's not exactly what i need.

**To put it in short** , i need a vm or a process that simulates to be a vcenter server ,  that you could authenticate against and maybe retrieve a bunch of virtual machines.

Thanks !!

Comment: I found this: http://www.sureskillz.com/2012/09/16/installing-esxi-5-1-vcenter-5-1-on-virtualbox/ , which is a very decent option! i think

Comment: I've never used it, and it's not officially supported, but looks like [vCenter Server Simulator](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2013/09/new-vcenter-server-simulator-20.html) might be applicable.

Comment: You can install your own vCenter 6.0 using trial licence, the installation process is relatively easy and done by a script - http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2015/03/ultimate-automation-guide-to-deploying-vcsa-6-0-part-4-vcenter-server-management-node.html

Answer (score 0):

Run vCenter inside VMware Fusion / Workstation.

Remember to keep your VMs lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

As for the REST API that shipped with vCenter 6.5 you can use Wiremock. VMware employee and dev Steve Trefethen has an example [repo here](https://github.com/strefethen/vmware-sdk-rest-mock).

Answer (score 0):

[vcsim](https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/tree/master/vcsim) - A vCenter and ESXi API based simulator

This package implements a vSphere Web Services (SOAP) SDK endpoint intended for testing consumers of the API. While the mock framework is written in the Go language, it can be used by any language that can talk to the vSphere API.